# What is the function of "ever" in this sentence and what is its relation (as a modifier) to another phrase in the sentence

Tags: adverbs, adverbials

> I have loved the circus **ever** since I was a child.

Is *ever* modifying **since**, **was** or **loved**.

The word ever is listed in most dictionaries as an adverb. I describe word functions as narrowly as possible, and the function of adverbs is: "an adverb modifies a verb, adjective or another adverb"

The most obvious/ closest modifying relation is to the word *since*, but that is a conjunction, and conflicts with my definition of the word function.

Comment: _Ever_ modifies _since_ ('at all times since I was a child').

Comment: Adverbs don't always modify verbs, adjectives, or adverbs: "An adverb is a word or an expression that generally modifies a verb, adjective, another adverb, determiner, clause, preposition, or sentence." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb Note that since can be adverb, conjunction, or preposition.

Comment: 'Continuously' would do the same job here, semantically, but 'ever since' seems more cohesive to me. Indeed, many dictionaries have a separate entry for the fixed phrase _ever since_, an argument for considering it as a single lexeme. / One has to be careful in applying the term 'modifier'. The _time constraint_ on 'continuously' here is 'in the time between my childhood and now'. Certainly, 'I have loved the circus continuously', though stodgy, works;  'I have loved the circus ever' certainly doesn't. Yes, 'The dwarves have ever suspected the elves' would be fine written by Tolkien.

Comment: "Since" is not a conjunction but a preposition. Here, it is modified by the adverb "ever".

Comment: _Ever since_ is a fixed phrase, emphasizing the continuous nature of the time span. Neither part needs to "modify" anything, any more than _good_ modifies _bye_.

Comment: If "ever since" was a fixed phrase, dropping the "ever" component would change the meaning of "since", but it very often doesn't.

Comment: @JohnLawler; @BillJ - Thanks John (and Bill), so then the phrase 'ever since' functions as either a preposition with a clause as landmark or a conjunction joining the clause to the sentence. My preference is to view words like "since" and "until' as having functional scope - if they are followed by a clause they function as a conjunction and if the are followed by anything else they function as a preposition. In my approach, preposition cannot take clauses as landmarks, and conjunctions must be followed by a clause.

Comment: @UbuEnglish At word level, "ever since" is not a grammatical unit, not a constituent, but a PP with "since" as head and "ever" as modifier. Note that subordinating conjunctions are meaningless markers of subordination while most prepositions have independent meanings. With items like "before", "after", and "**since**" there's the further point that they uncontroversially occur as prepositions when they have an NP as complement, and there's no basis for assigning them to different categories according as they take an NP or a clause -- or no complement at all.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - terminology is hard to use precisely when various theories use the same terms in different ways. When I said modifer, I paused because while 'ever' adds meaning to 'since', it doesen't actually modify (change) how we interpret it, As Johm points out, it just emphasizes duration. I like the term complementing, complementation and complement to refer to words and phrases that add, select, complete or change the meaing of other words or phrases. I know I'm using it in a very broad way, but that seems useful to me. And easier for students to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that *ever* is modifying "since," or rather the whole clause "since I was a child." It is indeed an adverb.

> I describe word functions as narrowly as possible, and the function of adverbs is: "an adverb modifies a verb, adjective or another adverb."

This is why others have not adopted your definition of the word "adverb"; it fails to account for words like "ever" in the sentence you provide.

Comment: Well, I tell my students that this is just a word with functional scope. It can influence the meaning of verbs and verb phrases, and clauses. It can also modify a conjunction (since) and by extension the clause it introduces with since. I guess I need to add clause to my definition

Comment: It can also modofy a noun phrase: "Ever the man of action, he scaled to wall to rescue the old woman."